# Quando usar "demais" e "de mais?"

Tags: ortografia, advérbios, locuções-adverbias

Nas frases "São perguntas de mais" e "São perguntas demais?" existe diferença? Quando usar "demais" e "de mais".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Demais**

usamos o vocábulo **`demais`** em duas situações básicas.

1ª - Como **advérbio de intensidade** (equivalente a muito), com sentido de "excessivamente, além da conta" ou "muitíssimo". Esses advérbios podem modificar um verbo, um adjetivo, ou mesmo outro advérbio(os demais só modificam verbos):

**Exs:**

- Eu **comi** demais.
- Vocês **comem** demais.
- O Automóvel é **caro** demais.

2ª - Pode ser um **pronome indefinido** significando "os outros, os restantes".
Como é um **pronome adjetivo**, sempre vai acompanhar um **substantivo** (expresso ou elíptico).

**Exs:**
- Convidaram João e os **demais** amigos.
- Contrate esta operadora e dispense as **demais**.

## **De mais**

A locução **de mais**, formada pela preposição **de**e o advérbio mais, significa "de sobra", "a mais", e opõe-se simetricamente à locução "**de menos**".

**Ex:**

- Uns têm coisas **de mais**, outros de **menos**.

O dicionário Aurélio diz: "capaz de causar estranheza, anormal".

**Ex:**

- Não vejo nada **de mais** em sua aparência.

Answer (score 8):

`demais` é uma palavra utilizada principalmente como um [advérbio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adv%C3%A9rbio), corretamente empregue quando nos referimos a excessos ou exageros:

> Ele está a comer demais.

`de mais` é uma [locução adverbial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_adverbial) que nos dá a noção de maior quantidade, como que o oposto a de menos. Tem um significado parecido com a locução a mais:

> Cor perfeita, nem vermelho de mais, nem vermelho de menos.

Já para o teu exemplo em particular, a versão correta será:

> São perguntas de mais

Porque estamos a lidar com quantidade, com algo a mais.

Comment: Zuul é "bom demais" ou "bom de mais"? E porquê? Não estou a entender neste caso.