# «bom de mais» ou «bom demais»?

Tags: ortografia, expressões, advérbios

Já temos a pergunta [Quando usar “demais” e “de mais?”](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/79/153) mas e no caso de «ser bom» é "ser bom demais", "ser bom de mais" ou dá os dois dependendo do que se quer dizer?

Esta minha duvida apareceu quando vi [este vídeo](http://ensina.rtp.pt/artigo/qual-e-a-forma-correta-bom-demais-ou-bom-de-mais/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Morfologicamente falando (em PT-pt):

- **demais**: pronome ou determinante demonstrativo (equivalente a "outros", "restantes", etc.); advérbio de modo (o mesmo que "demasiadamente)"; advérbio conectivo (equivalente a "para além disso").
- **de mais**: locução adverbial com o valor de quantidade (substituível por um qualquer quantificador a meu ver como "bastantes" por exemplo)

No vídeo parecem apenas reconhecer **demais** como advérbio conectivo ou pronome, o que é errado.
No caso específico de **bom demais/de mais** parece ter um valor de intensidade mais relacionado com o **demais** (em demasia) do que de quantidade mais relacionado com o **de mais**.

Desconhecendo qualquer significado idiomático da expressão **de mais**, arriscaria, portanto, a dizer que a RTP está errada e que o correto seria *"Bom demais".*

Comment: Concordo com a sua resposta, mas em pt-BR "demais" é advérbio de intensidade.

Answer (score 1):

**Não vejo como "de mais" possa ser usado após o adjetivo "bom". Estaria alguém querendo dizer "bom em excesso" ao invés de "muito bom"?**

O contrário de "de mais" é "de menos"

- "O churrasco tinha sal de mais" x "O churrasco tinha sal de menos"
- "Temos voluntários de mais" x "Temos voluntários de menos"

Já o contrário de "bom de mais" seria "bom de menos" e não faria sentido.

Em pt-BR dizemos "bom demais" que significa "muito bom", como em

- "isso aqui está bom demais"
- "o jantar estava bom demais"
- e até no regionalismo "o feijão estava bom demais da conta, sô." Um modo de falar típico de alguns habitantes do estado de Minas Gerais, onde "demais da conta" significa "muito, muito" e "sô" significa "senhor".

Por outro lado, pode ser que em determinado contexto as palavras "bom", "de", "mais" venham exatamente nessa ordem sem que constituam uma unidade semântica.

Comment: "O churrasco tinha sal demais" estaria errado?

Comment: @bfavaretto    Acredito que esteja correto (...tinha sal demais = tinha muito sal)  mas não encontrei uma fonte para confirmar.

Comment: Por que "de mais" para indicar demasia (excesso)? Se o substantivo é uma única palavra, qual o sentido do advérbio ser composto de duas?

Comment: E "bom demais" significa "bom em excesso" mesmo. Hipérboles como esta são comuns na língua informal brasileira: "bom de doer", "absurdo de tão bom", "bom de morrer", etc. Curiosamente, no inglês, existe uma expressão similar: "too good".

Answer (score -2):

Acho que a rtp está errada. O correto é bom demais. De mais e de menos são sinais.